# How to get the procedure call from a DMV in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using SQL Server 2008 and we need to catch the s procedure call using DMV and stored it in the table for tracking. Is it possible to get the stored procedure call ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe not completly what you are looking for, but it might be start. If you are looking for the queries that have been running, with or without stored procedures, you might wanna look at this

```
select  case
          when r.statement_end_offset = -1 then 
            substring(s.text, (r.statement_start_offset / 2), len(s.text))
          else 
            substring(s.text, (r.statement_start_offset / 2), (r.statement_end_offset /     2) - (r.statement_start_offset / 2))
        end as statement_text
      , q.query_plan
      , r.cpu_time
      , r.reads as request_reads
      , r.writes as request_writes
      , r.logical_reads as request_logical_reads
from    sys.dm_exec_requests r
        cross apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text(r.sql_handle) s
        cross apply sys.dm_exec_query_plan(r.plan_handle) q
```

It gives you all the queries that have been run.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for `sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats`? ([MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280701%28v=sql.100%29.aspx))

> Returns aggregate performance statistics for cached stored procedures.
>   The view returns one row for each cached stored procedure plan, and
>   the lifetime of the row is as long as the stored procedure remains
>   cached. When a stored procedure is removed from the cache, the
>   corresponding row is eliminated from this view. At that time, a
>   Performance Statistics SQL trace event is raised similar to
>   sys.dm_exec_query_stats.

You should be able to selectwhatever stored proc execution statistics you need from this into your audit table. If you wish to extend your auditing to include ad-hoc queries that aren't necessarily stored procs, consider taking a look at [sys.dm_exec_query_stats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189741%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) instead.